# Filter table by empty cells

Tags: yadcf

I have a table I would like to filter by code and show only rows after yadcf.init (Yadcf 0.9.3) having column8 value is empty.

```
{ column_number: 8, filter_type: "range_date", 
  date_format: "yy.mm.dd",  
  column_data_type: 'text' }
```

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(table, [[8, {from: "", to: ""}]]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You better use the [exResetFilters](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/c7f356215a7ffebc95e3f995ed95ce5d9777e951/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L340) method, read docs:

> - exResetFilters
>                 Description:        Allows to reset specific filters externally/programmatically (support ALL filter types!!!) , can be
>     used for resetting one or more filters
>                 Arguments:          table_arg: (variable of the datatable)
>                                     array with columns numbers
>                                     noRedraw:   (boolean) , use it if you don't want your table to be reloaded after the filter reset,
>                                                 for example if you planning to call exFilterColumn function right after the
>     exResetFilters (to avoid two AJAX requests)
>                 Usage example:      yadcf.exResetAllFilters(oTable, [1,2]);